# Remove the 'starting at' text

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, phtml

On my website, I want to remove the 'Starting at:' string in front of the price, only when the product has a certain category.

I am now searching in `template/catalog/product/price.phtml`, and found this code:

```
<?php if ($showMinPrice): ?>
  <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Starting at:') ?></span>
<?php endif ?>
```

Which most likely displays the text. Problem is, when I do changes to these div's, even adding classes or whatever, it does nothing. Is there maybe another place where the 'Starting at:' text is loaded in?

**Progress so far:**

- Via template hints, I saw that the problem is existing in the price.phtml file, not a suprise
- I tried to remove the code above, but it still displays the string
- Also tried flushing the cache (even when it's disabled) and even reindexing, did not work

Comment: can you try to on template path (from backend) from that particular web page ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Go [this](http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints) link and try to solve your issue

Comment: @NewBeeInMagento already did that, price is generated by price.phtml. But like I said, I can even remove the code from the file, and it will still generate 'Starting at:'

Comment: can you try to access that particular attribute in Catalog > Attribute > Manage Attribute **price** labal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem via a different approach. Instead of removing the string when the product has a certain category, I gave the item a special classname whenever the product has a certain category.

Via this classname, I give the string a `display:none`. Seemed to work.

Comment: this is not proper approach

Comment: I know, but it works for now. I would love to spend some more time in this matter, but I simply can't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove for some category then you can follow below code

```
<?php if ($showMinPrice): ?>
  <span class="price-label">
      <?php 
        $remove_category_id =array(1,2,3); //category id where you dont want to show this text
        if(Mage::registry('current_category')):
            if(in_array(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId(), $remove_category_id)):
                echo '';
            else:
                    echo $this->__('Starting at:')
            endif;
        else:
            echo $this->__('Starting at:')
        endif;
      ?>
      <?php echo $this->__('Starting at:') ?>
  </span>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: No, I know how that works. My question is where the string is loaded into the website, in which file

Comment: Price comes from price.phtml only May be you are looking in wrong theme

Comment: That's very weird, I check my own price.phtml, the one from the RWD default theme and the one of the base default theme. :/

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen i think template hint will solve your problem.

Comment: Just on template path hint and check , might be some extension has change the price.phtml with their price.phtml

Comment: Turned on template hints, problem seems to lie in the price.html file, no suprise there. But whatever I do, it does not change anything. I can even remove the code that generates the string, and it will still display

Comment: Got it your issue With cache refresh magento cache or remove the contain of `var/cache` folder and your problem would solve

Comment: Cache is disabled, flushed it anyway. Did not work

Comment: same file please check for other lines that work or not may be this piece of code not from there or come from other part of file